# Looping Through Boolean Parameters

Tags: vb.net

I have a generic question to see if anyone can help me with a better solution.

I have a .NET method that takes in 20+ boolean values, passed in individually.

For each parameter that is true I need to add a value to list.

Is there a more efficient way to add the values to the list besides have an if statement for each boolean?

Example:

```
Public Function Example(ByVal pblnBool1 as boolean, _
                        ByVal pblnBool2 as boolean, _
                        ByVal pblnBool3 as boolean)
             If pblnBool1 then
                list += "A"
             End If
             If pblnBool2 then
                list += "B"
             End If  
End Function
```

Obviously this code isn't correct but it shows what I'm trying to do.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to do something different for each boolean parameter?

Answer (score 2):

First off, having 20+ params sucks.

Secondly, you can use the `ParamArray` keyword to declare that you want the values passed to you in an array.  (I don't think this is CLS compliant, meaning some languages won't be able to call your function without bundling the values into an array.  But VB and C# can both easily work with each other's param arrays.)  If you don't want to do that, you can always create the array yourself in your function.  But i'd rather let the language and/or framework do that for me.

This is not optimized or anything; it's just an example.

```
sub Example(paramarray bools() as Boolean)
    static vals() as String = {"A", "B", "C"}
    if bools.Length > vals.Length then
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format( _
            "Too many params! ({0} max, {1} passed)", _
            vals.Length, bools.Length _
        ))
    end if 
    for i as Integer = 0 to bools.Length - 1
        if bools(i) then list += vals(i)
    next
end sub
```

I assume that `list` is some member variable, since it's not defined in your code.  If you intend for it to be the return value, then declare it in the function, and return it at the end.  (And of course, turn `sub Example(...)` and `end sub` into `function Example(...) as String` and `end function`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 32 or fewer booleans to pass, you can use an instance of BitVector32.  This allows to pass them all in a single integer.  It provides methods for setting and retrieving the values.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array of boolean values and do a `for...each` loop through it. Or if you need to be selective, a 2-D array.